# ASP.NET Core API - Patch method without using JsonPatchDocument

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Given the following model

```
public class User
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

and lets assume the following as it's Json payload

```
{
    "id": "b3fe876d-5050-4bd6-af28-c9941d837c18",
    "Name": "John",
    "Address": "Germany"
}
```

I am trying to patch this via my API endpoint, lets say I need to update Name key, using JsonPatchDocument in .net the payload would be like

```
 {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/Name",
    "value": "Jack"
  }
```

The above works fine!

However we are trying to achieve the same things by sending the same Json payload through the API instead of the Patch specified format. So something like below

```
{
    "Name": "Jack"
}
```

So it would only update that specific property/ key in the Json/ Model

Not sure if this is even possible, but this has been brought up by a friend who has implemented this using DJango and Python. Hence we are trying to achieve the same thing in .Net

Comment: Why should it not be possible? Or where do you see a problem? Looks pretty easy to me. But you may see problems because of some domain specifics in your case we don't know and you should name them.

Comment: No we don't have any sort of domain specifics or complications, it's just as simple as it looks. But I don't know the approach towards that. I'd appreciate it if you could share your method of doing it.

Comment: In the endpoint validate the partial (user) object in the payload. When you have an own model for that (you should as that model should not have or allow an id here, the id belongs into the route) you may work with attributes on that model for that. Then retrieve the existing model from your repository copy the properties you have been given over, validate the merged model and then write it back via your repository.

Comment: That makes sense, what if there is a filed with Json string contents, and that also need to be patched. So the field is within the same entity which is being patched but the field itself contains Json string and same as the parent entity we need to update only a small part of the Json string inside the field!

Comment: I would assume you have a model for that field also and to that the same applies as to the surrounding model on how to patch.

Comment: Like @Ralf said,you can retrieve the existing model from your repository,I think you can use the SetValues method of EntityEntry, then modify the state of the entity to Modified, and finally return it through your responsitory..

Comment: That's the thing there is no model for that, it's the whole point of it, we want the user have the freedom of constructing their own json string and be able to provide additional data. So an arbitrary json string which also need to be patchable .

Comment: Ah. So you have something that is fully random and should be mergable by random rules? The only thing that you know is it is json? And you think there aren't any domain specific complications ;) You might have a look at JsonNet's Merge operation https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/MergeJson.htm if thats fits you. I'm pretty sure there are restrictions on how things can change and you need to find out if you can live with those restrictions.

Comment: You can see this [article](https://hamidmosalla.com/2018/04/14/asp-net-core-api-patch-method-without-using-jsonpatchdocument/),maybe it will help you

Comment: @Yinqiu thanks very much, I have seen that article, but it uses a custom model very similar to JsonPatchDocument, which I am trying to avoid

Comment: @Ralf lol you are right that's the complicated part of it. Yes, that might helps however what if a key value is removed , would that also remove it in the destination or just ignore it! I will need to try them, but you are right we need to set some rules there otherwise it would be very complication!